# How do I flip a column in mysql that has data structured: 'last name, first name'?

Tags: sql, mysql, string

**I want to create a new column in a MYSQL table that has Fn Ln instead of Ln, Fn.  Most of my data is printed Fn Ln.**

Another idea is to incorporate a string function each time there is an output (php based) but that seems to waste resources.  Finally, I couldn't find the syntax (loop or foreach) for my php function anyway.

Here is the working php function that I got from a previous post:

```
   $name = "Lastname, Firstname";
    $names = explode(", ", $name);
    $name = $names[1] . " " . $names[0];
```

Comment: Suggest you never store the whole name in one column. This is poor practice whether you do firstname lastname or lastname, firstname.
It isn't so easy to actually parse these as names have spaces and sometimes commas that are not the split beteewn first and lastname. How would the program know how to reverse Linda Sue De La Rosa  or Smith, MD, John A. or Miller, Steve, III. Datas stored this way inevitably gets messy. Plus it's harder to query. Always split first name middle name lastname and suffix into spearate fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the mysql function [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get a portion of a string up to an specified number or occurrences.

Make sure to change anything I've prefixed with a $ to what you want it called

```
# Add new column
alter table $TABLE add $newField varchar(40); # or something like that

# Populate new data
update $TABLE set $newField = CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX($oldField,',',2),',',-1),
  ' ',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX($oldField,',',1)
);
```

That splits the name field on , and puts the second part first, in the new field you created.

Comment: It was poorly formatted previously, and didn't contain a link to the MYSQL function would be my guess.

Comment: it must update 2 columns not one. I wonder if SO users ever learn to think, not to read and write only.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I find this comment particularly ironic.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at using

[SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

[RIGHT(str,len)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_right)

And

[LEFT(str,len)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

[CONCAT(str1,str2,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Also, why are these fields stored in a single column in the first place? Would it not have been easier if they were stored in the correct Fields FirName, and separate column LastName?

Im a bit more of a SQL Server but you can try something like

```
SELECT  CONCAT( RIGHT(FirstNameLastName,LEN(FirstNameLastName) - SUBSTRING_INDEX(FirstNameLastName, ' ', 1)),
                ', ',
                LEFT(FirstNameLastName,SUBSTRING_INDEX(FirstNameLastName, ' ', 1) - 1)
                )
FROM    YourTable
```

EDIT:

Sql Server would have looked like (interest sakes)

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        FirstNameLastName VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'Foo Bar'

SELECT  RIGHT(FirstNameLastName,LEN(FirstNameLastName) - PATINDEX('% %', FirstNameLastName)) + ', ' + LEFT(FirstNameLastName,PATINDEX('% %', FirstNameLastName) - 1)
FROM    @Table
```

Comment: Yes,  you're right about the efficiency of storing as two fields.  But I imported the data from exiting software and that's the way it's stored.  I will will a look at your link.

Comment: So what, @ggg ? he is talking of your current database. Make it 2 fields now, since you're rewriting it anyway. That's the point, not your old software